# Parsing date string with year omitted

Tags: python, datetime

I am given a series of date strings of the format `'July 24'`, i.e. `'%B %d'`. I would like to parse these strings such that the year corresponds to the most recent date, so if today is July 24, 2019 then `'July 24'` should be parsed as 24/7/2019 but `'July 25'` should be parsed as 25/7/2018. I was hoping that the `datetime` module could do this, but it just sets the year to 1900.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('July 24', '%B %d')                                            
datetime.datetime(1900, 7, 24, 0, 0)
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this than to manually parse the dates according to my rule?

Comment: You could set `year` to the year of `datetime.datetime.now()`. If it is greater than `datetime.datetime.now()` then set the year to `datetime.datetime.now()`'s year - 1

Comment: @Silveris Yes, that's what I meant by manually parsing the dates. I suppose it's not enough extra work to justify an option for this in the datetime module...

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in a single line, and I won't be surprised if there's an even easier way:

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
before = datetime.strptime('July 24', '%B %d')
print(before.replace(year=today.year if before.replace(year=1) <= today.replace(year=1) else today.year - 1))
after = datetime.strptime('July 25', '%B %d')
print(after.replace(year=today.year if after.replace(year=1) <= today.replace(year=1) else today.year - 1))
```

Outputs

```
2019-07-24 00:00:00
2018-07-25 00:00:00
```

Of course this can be micro-optimized by not calling `before.replace` (or `after.replace`) twice, but as an example this is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind about this issue is that `datetime.datetime` has `'year'` as it's first positional argument, which is required to create an actual instance of it.  So if you import the class `datetime.dateime` as `datetime` and make reference to it's methods without first delcaring an instance of it, then you are relying on the default values of attribs like `datetime.datetime.year`.

Here is a function that accepts a string, `mydate`, whose format is `"%B %d"`, and returns a `datetime` instance with it's `year` attribute set to `2019` (but keeping month and day the same) if `datetime.datetime.today().month == datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, "%B %d").month` and `datetime.datetime.today().day == datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, "%B %d").day`, or with it's `year` attribute set to 2018 in any other case.

You can call `strftime("%Y/%B/%d")` to get the string for further along in your greater procedure, or ad it to this definition.

```py
import datetime

def make_year_float(mydate):

    dt = datetime.datetime

    d1 = dt.today().month, dt.today().day

    the_date = dt.strptime(mydate, "%B %d")
    d2 = the_date.month, the_date.day

    if d1 == d2:
        return dt(2019, the_date.month, the_date.day)
    elif d1 != d2:
        return dt(2018, the_date.month, the_date.day)
```